# Is there any easy way to create these stepper buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

[image: Stepper buttons]

I need such buttons like month and year buttons in image. A library named Ystepperview is available for ios but not found this for android. If anyone implemented such buttons let me know what is the easy way to create this view.

Comment: Asking for libraries will get your question closed, so I removed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML:**

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/your_shape"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/yourLeftIcon"/>


        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="#fbae41"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="JAN"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/yourRightIcon"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

**SHAPE your_shape.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#999a97"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
    <corners android:radius="24dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

**output:**

[image]

Change the corners android:radius="24dip" to the correct radius, and the background color solid android:color="#999a97" and you will get the example view.